# Reduce excess Log[]

Tags: simplifying-expressions, output

I am trying to solve a differential equation using DSolve:

```
DSolve[y'[t] == t^10 eps^-y[t], y[t], t]
```

And get the following output:

```
{{y[t] -> Log[-(-(t^11/11) - C[1]) Log[eps]]/Log[eps]}}
```

Is there any way to get Mathematica to automatically reduce `Log[eps]` to one? Or

Comment: What are you expecting to happen to the expression? The first $\log(\epsilon)$ is inside the numerator's $\log$, and the second is not, so there isn't a term which will just cancel.

Comment: Well Log(ϵ) is in the denominator and the value is 1, so I am wondering why its shown at all.

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing $\epsilon$ with Euler's constant $e$?

Comment: You are absolutely correct, I misread and confused the two. Thanks for clearing it up!